# Use regex to check if a string contains some of the keywords but some are excluded in Java

Tags: regex

Let's say given two sets of keywords:

```
Set #1: apple,banana,pear
Set #2: ?,&,+,version
```

Want to write a regex to accept any of the strings in Set #1 but exclude any of Set #2.

For example: "This is an apple" is matched but "Is this an apple?" is not.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(?=.*(apple|banana|pear))(?!.*(\?|&|\+|version)).*/
```